# Is it okay to use drupal_goto() from within a node?

Tags: nodes

I implemented a node that automatically adds a product to a cart using this function `uc_cart_add_item(33);`

but I want it to then redirect the visitor to the check out page.  I saw that drupal has a drupal_goto() function however this is essentially just a php Header(location: http://mysite.com/cart/checkout)  which usually shouldn't work if it is not done so before any content is spit out.

Now I got this to work and everything but I never liked the idea of just getting it to work, I'd like to get it right.  I thought of a script outside of the drupal environment but wasnt sure if I could use the ubercarts functions.  Does anyone have any ideas on a better way or is the using drupal_goto() within a node okay?

Just to say and I saw someone else who had a similar problem was that this did work, however the cron job time exceeded the time limit after I implemented this.  SO maybe not a good option like i thought.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bad idea and I wouldn't recommend doing it.  The cron error you see is most likely due to the Search module. During cron while the Search module is trying to index content, if it reaches a node containing a `drupal_goto()` it will hang and cron will error which could lead to more problems

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad idea to use it in the nodeapi. Drupal uses the decorator pattern in this API and interrupting that with a redirect won't give the other modules a chance to operate on the node.

Assuming you're submitting a form: The form API (which also uses the same pattern) will let you redirect with $form['#redirect']. But be sure to use the global $base_url in your path. It's a caveat in the form API.

Something like:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  global $base_url;
  $form['#redirect'] = $base_url .'/path';
}
```

You'd probably want to avoid hard coding the path but that should point you in the right direction...

Answer (score 2):

This is what I used when we really needed `drupal_goto()` without creating modules to do it (D6)

```
//normally script name is index.php, but is cron.php if it's loaded via cron
//do not execute the drupal_goto if script name is cron.php,
// or if the node is loaded for anything other than being viewed

$script_name= str_replace(base_path(), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

$arg0 = arg(0);
$arg2 = arg(2);

if($script_name != 'cron.php'
   && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/admin/reports/status/run-cron'
   && $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']
   && !($arg0 == 'node' && !empty($arg2)))
{
  drupal_goto('node/123');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that *within a node* means *when viewing a node page*, it is possible to safely call `drupal_goto()`. In a [`hook_nodeapi()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) when `$op == 'view'` (Drupal 6) or [`hook_node_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) (Drupal 7) implementation, you should take care to call `drupal_goto()` only if the node is actually viewed as a full page. This will prevent other modules' hooks to run, but as they should only add content to display to `$node->content`, this shouldn't be an issue.

In Drupal 6, something like

```
function MODULE_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  if ($op == 'view' && $a3 === FALSE && $a4 == TRUE) {
    $page_node = menu_get_object();
    if (!empty($page_node) && $page_node->nid == $node->nid) {
      //It is safe to call drupal_goto() from here
    }
  }
}
```

In Drupal 7, something like

```
function MODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($view_mode == 'full' && node_is_page($node)) {
    //It is safe to call drupal_goto() from here
  }
}
```

It is unsafe to call `drupal_goto()` for all the other values of `$op` or from other `hook_node_*` implementations. `drupal_goto()` will end the request processing and prevent hooks from other module to run.